# Deciding whether a system of linear integer inequalities has infinitely many solutions

Tags: inequalities, integer-programming

I have a quick question that I am struggling to find a solution to:

Given a system of linear integer inequalities $A\textbf{x} \leq \textbf{b}$, where $A\in \mathbb{Z}^{m\times n}$ and $\textbf{b}\in\mathbb{Z}^{m}$,  is it possible to decide whether this system has infinitely many solutions?

Any help or pointers to the relevant literature are appreciated!

EDIT: I am only interested in integer solutions, i.e., the question is whether there are infinitely many integer solutions.

Comment: I am not sure. If a polytope determined by the system is bounded then there are definitely finitely many integer solutions, but if this polytope is not bounded can it still be the case that we have finitely many solutions?

Comment: Welcome Alexandra! Yes, $4x \leq 6$, $-4x \leq -2$ in $x$ and $y$ with $y$ unconstrained is unbounded but has no integer solutions.